# What happens if I don't specify the user agent in requests.get()?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

Can someone please explain what happens if I don't specify my user agent in `requests.get(url)`?

If I specify, it'd be like the following:

```
user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
requests.get(url, headers=user_agent)
```

And if I don't, it'd simply be

```
requests.get(url)
```

What difference does it make? And what's the default for user agent if I don't specify?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The server will read your request and is free to do anything based on the user agent information. Usually, I believe, the server does not care about it at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the defaults headers using this code

```
requests.utils.default_headers()
```

Answer (score 6):

The default Python Requests user agent will be used. In my case (Python 3.9.1) the default user agent is `python-requests/2.25.0`.

Some websites block access from non web browser User Agents to prevent scraping.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connected to a webpage, your browser sends a user agent to the website. Not specifying a user agent has consequences for websites that block webscraping, as they will detect you are using an automated browser. So by using a user agent, you will mimick a normal browser, thus less likely to be blocked by the website.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#page-46):

> The "User-Agent" header field contains information about the user
> agent originating the request, which is often used by servers to help
> identify the scope of reported interoperability problems, to work
> around or tailor responses to avoid particular user agent
> limitations, and for analytics regarding browser or operating system
> use.  A user agent SHOULD send a User-Agent field in each request
> unless specifically configured not to do so.

From my point of view, this value is not very useful for you if you are web scraping.

Some web site can block your requests if your program doesn’t look like a web browser. It cost nothing to use “Mozilla/5.0”.

Answer (score -1):

The `User-Agent` header when typically sent by a web browser or other http client, does not have ANY defined meaning.  It simply tells the server something about the client, and the server can do whatever it wants with that information.

Normally this would be used to alter the response to maintain compatibility with different clients (browsers).  For example, a web application might respond with a simplified site if it detects a mobile browser via the `User-Agent` string.

But there are no hard and fast rules here.  The server may just ignore this header completely.

In other cases you may find applications, especially older ones, that were coded to rely on features that were available only in specific browsers, and that will not return a useful response if they don't recognize the client as a browser that they like.  In that case, it's useful to set the `User-Agent` header to that of a well-supported browser that the application is coded to handle.  It's not how things SHOULD work, but sometimes that's necessary.

By default, `requests` sends a user-agent header which identifies the version of the requests package you are using, the python version and the operating system.

Most web applications aren't written to recognize `python-requests` as a browser so, if they are coded to be particular about the browser used to access them, they may not return a good response, in which case you'll need to fake the header to make it look like you are using a more common browser that the server side application recognizes.

Comment: This is a really good answer! I have another somewhat relevant question if I'm allowed to ask- are the user agents unique? i.e. I can find my Safari user agent from searching "my user agent" in Google from my Safari browser. Let's say I have another laptop of the exact same build, same OS version, same Safari version and same everything... Will the user agent be the same from the two browsers?

Comment: Yes, they should be exactly the same.  Obviously since the client (browser) generates the string, it can do whatever it wants...  but for all the major browsers eg. Safari, Firefox, Chrome etc the format of the user-agent they generate is well known and you can easily search online for documentation as to what the different parts of the string represent.